# sprintf in Matlab: use compact representation, but always include trailing zero

Tags: string, matlab, string-formatting, printf

I'm writing a function that requires floating-point values to be converted to strings to be passed into (closed) C code. String conversion is the slowest part of my code and the input arrays can be very large. [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) is fast and the `g` conversion character results in compact a representation:

```
x = [-1.75 0 1 pi 2^57];
sprintf('%.17g ',x)
```

which returns

```
-1.75 0 1 3.1415926535897931 1.4411518807585587e+17
```

Like with `sprintf`'s C equivalent, [insignificant zeros are not printed](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq0z8vc-1) when the `g` or `G` conversion characters are specified. However, the C code I'm using requires that numeric values include the decimal point and trailing zero. Another option that retains the same precision is:

```
x = [-1.75 0 1 pi 2^57];
sprintf('%.17f ',x)
```

which returns

```
-1.75000000000000000 0.00000000000000000 1.00000000000000000 3.14159265358979312 144115188075855872.00000000000000000
```

But this leads to ballooning of the string array (the input vectors can be big and complex-valued).

---

How can I efficiently and compactly (speed and memory) print my numbers to strings while adding a trailing zero if needed and produce an output like this?

```
-1.75 0.0 1.0 3.1415926535897931 1.4411518807585587e+17
```

Ideally this could be done directly within the format string so that `sprintf` can do the work. If that doesn't work, what other options are there and what's the fastest? `regexprep` is far too slow so don't even think about it. If you like, you might use `x = repmat([-1.75 0 1 pi 2^57],1e5,1);` as your test array for timing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I define what format specs I want to use.
Then I determine which is appropriate and create the format spec string.

```
x = [-1.75 0 1 pi 2^57];

s = {'%.17g ', '%.1f'};
idx = (x-floor(x) < 0.1 & x < 10^9) + 1;
fspec = reshape(char(s(idx))', 1, []);
```

Gives me

```
>> sprintf(fspec, x)

ans =

-1.75 0.0  1.0  3.1415926535897931 1.4411518807585587e+17
```

Comment: I like how you used a cell array. On my machine and R2013a, this is about seven times slower than `sprintf('%.17g ',x)` using `x = repmat(x,1e5,1);` to test. Almost all of the additional time is spent in `sprintf` due to the longer, more complicated format string. It would still be nice to be able to do this with some form of a single format string.

Comment: I'm currently using a compact version of this. It seems that a lot of the slowdown from `sprintf` is in printing many very large or very small values using the `g` or `e` conversion character.